# While importing the data from .txt file into teradata table i am getting invalid timestamp error

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

I have a .txt file contains timestamp column like 9/1/2020 00:00:00.000000 and some other columns.but while importing into teradata SQL assistant getting invalid time stamp error.
please help me the way as I need to import file data into volatile and has to do minus operation between these file table and actual table.

and the column datatype define in teradata table is timestamp(6)

Comment: How are you attempting to import the data?  Show at least the code for the timestamp column.

Comment: Single-digit month and day will be an issue. Either change the source text format or use a RegEx to ensure 2-digit values, then specify that format in a `CAST` or  `TO_TIMESTAMP`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57635651